# Pass parameter via ICommand

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvmcross

The following works if I do not pass anything from the View.

**View.cs**

```
ViewModel.ReloadCommand.Execute(null);
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public ICommand ReloadCommand
{
  get
   {
      return new MvxCommand(async () =>
         {
            await RefreshStudentList();
         });
    }
}
```

However I need to pass a parameter, I wonder how could I do that?

```
ViewModel.ReloadCommand.Execute(xxx);
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public ICommand ReloadCommand
{
  get
   {
      return new MvxCommand(async () =>
         {
            await RefreshStudentList(xxx);
         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do async operation MvvmCross also has a `MvxAsyncCommand` which also can take a parameter as the regular `MvxCommand`.

It looks something like this:

```
public ICommand ReloadCommand
{
    return new MvxAsyncCommand(DoAsyncStuff);
}

private Task DoAsyncStuff(MyType type)
{

}
```

Any command can be executed with a parameter like:

```
ViewModel.ReloadCommand.Execute(myParameter);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with MvvmCross, but from what I can tell, it would be something like this:

```
public ICommand ReloadCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand<XXXType>(async (xxx) =>
            {
                await RefreshRoutesList(xxx);
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, try initialize your `ViewModel` on your `View` first. Then, based on your code, the `ICommand` does only `RefreshRoutesList` function, so I will access the `RefreshRoutesList` directly from the `View`. To make the naming clear, I will use `MyView.cs` and `MyViewModel.cs`

**MyView.cs**

```
MyViewModel vm;
.
.
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    .... //other stuff
    vm = ViewModel as MyViewModel;
}
```

After doing that, you could call your function anywhere in your view using vm variable, i.e.

```
await vm.RefreshRoutesList(aParameter);
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer you might be looking for but...

My understanding of Mvvm is that it reflects the state of the View and reacts to Commands from the View.  Your parameter can be treated as State and as such should have its own Property on the ViewModel that it would be bound to.  Thus your Command would not have to pass a parameter.  This would also further de-couple the ViewModel from the View's implementation.